# Linux + ARM + KINECT + C# + MonoDevelop, is that possible?

Tags: c#, linux, arm, monodevelop, kinect

I am developing a project that involves creating a product composed of hardware and software that enables interaction with various features.

I'm still in the testing phase , however , is sent to the brain of this product is a mini computer ODROID U3 , running Xubunto 13.10.

In addition to other components , I want the system refer to the use of the Kinect , or any other similar , however , for the test phase only own a Kinect.

I'm more accustomed to the language C # ( . NET ) , I used in windows environment with Visual Studio and did some games in Unity3D . The MonoDevelop looks very interesting alternative for Linux , and I'm currently testing it.

Well, as you may have noticed, I 'm new at this , and I have not much knowledge in Linux , MonoDevelop as well as Kinect , and I'm having some doubts .

I'm already trying to put the Kinect running on Linux for two days and the results are not very encouraging , installed libfreenect , nite , OpenNI and sensorKinect , but so far , the closest I got was to run one or two samples , not all work . Maybe I'm not doing things correctly ...

So loved your help , opinion or tip the following:

- What is the best way to install and recognize the Kinect on Linux ?
- Is it possible to run applications on computers Kinect ARM architecture ?
- It is possible to develop applications for Kinect on Linux , with c# ?
- Is it possible to do this with MonoDevelop ? If yes, how to install or use the wrapper for this purpose?
- Does Microsoft user therms allow us to use Kinect on a different operating system, and sell a product with it?

Any help is welcome, and I want to thank the community already;)
Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a late reply but better late than never.

**What is the best way to install and recognize the Kinect on Linux?**

If you have a choice please opt for libfreenect (aka OpenKinect). It access the sensors at much lower level. If you have to go with OpenNI you must install SensorKinect driver as well.

**Is it possible to run applications on computers Kinect ARM architecture?**

Yes. Both OpenNI+Sensor Kinect and libfreenect work just fine on ARM architectures.

**It is possible to develop applications for Kinect on Linux , with c#?**

Yes. Check Mono. However, I do not trust the C# performance on linux/android. I never did on Windows either. On such a complicated platform I'd recommend Python wrappers. OpenNI has a mono wrapper and libfreenect does not. I think wrapping libfreenect into a mono wrapper is not that difficult considering they did it for Matlab.

**Is it possible to do this with MonoDevelop? If yes, how to install or use the wrapper for this purpose?**

Yes. 1) install dependancies (libusb, opengl, freeglut). 2) Clone and build OpenNI from github. 3) Clone and build SensorKinect from github.

PS. In OpenNI and SensorKinect folder edit Platform/Linux/Build/Common/Platform.Arm and comment out the "-mfloat-abi=softfp" CFLAG. This is essential when you build on ARM architecture since the processor has an FPU and is using hard floating point.

**Does Microsoft user therms allow us to use Kinect on a different operating system, and sell a product with it?**

As far as I know the answer is "Yes" (at least for Kinect 1). The Kinect sensor is an open architecture founded by PrimeSense (Apple bought this company now). Asus and other manufacturers relased several verisons of the same sensor. They are all supported by OpenNI. As for libfreenect support, you should keep an eye on the git hub users.